# Magento 2.4.3 - Show out of stock while backorder is on

Tags: magento2.4, stock, backorder

I'm looking for a way to show "out of stock" while the backorder is on.

The client wants backorder and shows "out of stock" as we will translate that to something else.

Is to notify to the customer that the product is out of stock but are able to order it.

Does anyone that has a solution for this?